# C# System.Net.Http Not recognizing definitions

Tags: c#, httpclient

(I'm using Visual Studio 2015)

I copied this function from another VS project (that works just fine). I noticed that I was getting errors at `tokenClient.SetBasicAuthentication()`.

Then i realized from the working code that this was referencing `System.Net.Http`.

So I added a the reference via `Add -> References`.

I was still getting the error. So I went to look for the Nuget package and Installed System.Net.Http v4.3.4 (by Microsoft).

I'm still getting this error. (see image - I also included code).

Can anyone help? Why can't I get `SetBasicAuthentication` to work?

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

// other code ......
// other code ......

public static async Task<string> querySite(string url)
{
    var tokenClient = new HttpClient();
    var postData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "grant_type", "client_credentials" }, { "scope", "site_integration_api" } });

    //Create TLS Security Protocol
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12;
    tokenClient.SetBasicAuthentication(clientID, clientSecret);

    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.PostAsync(loginUrl, postData);
    if (!tokenResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        throw new ApplicationException("Could not accept token. Ensure credentials are correct.");

    string tokenData = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    int start = tokenData.IndexOf(access_token_string) + access_token_string.Length + 1;
    int end = tokenData.IndexOf("\"", start + 1) - start;
    var accessToken = tokenData.Substring(start, end);

    //Call service to get XML
    var serviceClient = new HttpClient();
    serviceClient.SetBearerToken(accessToken);

    return await serviceClient.GetStringAsync(url);        
}
```

Comment: `SetBasicAuthentication` is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). You need to reference `HttpClientExtensions` and include the appropriate namespace.

Comment: The `System.Net.Http` NuGet package is a gateway to NuGet Hell (at least in Framework apps).  You probably want to remove it.  I don't see the `SetBasicAuthentication` method as being documented as a member of HttpClient on either the Framework or Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7).  What version of the framework are you using?  Have you tried digging into your "taken from" code to see where the function is defined (it might be a local Extension Method someone ginned up in that project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own extention method for basic authentication:

```
public static class HttpClientExtention
{
    public static void SetBasicAuthentication(this HttpClient client, string userName, string password)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{userName}:{password}")));
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for SetBasicAuthentication. What about SetBearerToken?

Comment: for bearer token it is `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");`